# How to open an URL in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, url, qt4, qtableview

**What is the best way to present a *clickable* URL in a `QTableView` (or `QTreeView`, `QListView`, etc...)**

Given a `QStandardItemModel` where some of the columns contain text with URLs I'd like them to become clickable and then handle the click by using `QDesktopServices::openURL()`

I was hoping there would be some easy way to leverage `QLabel`'s textInteraction flags and to cram them into the table. I can't believe there's not an easier way to handle this. I really hope I'm missing something.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to create a delegate to do the painting. The code should look something like this:

```
void RenderLinkDelegate::paint(
           QPainter *painter,
           const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
           const QModelIndex &index
           ) const
{
    QString text = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    if (text.isEmpty())
        return;

    painter->save();

    // I only wanted it for mouse over, but you'll probably want to remove
    // this condition
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
    {
        QFont font = option.font;
        font.setUnderline(true);
        painter->setFont(font);
        painter->setPen(option.palette.link().color());
    }
    painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, text);

    painter->restore();
}
```

Comment: Kaleb, this is the only way to paint hyperlinks in a tableview, and topicstarter wanted to realize, how to make clickable links there, without puttings a QTextBrowser into every cell.

Comment: I am very concerned, how can I do it, too, if you know the way, please, tell us, how.

Comment: You would then also reimplement QAbstractItemDelegate::editorEvent() in order to receive mouse clicks, and if the click is on a link, use QDesktopServices::openUrl() to open the URL.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use delegates to *render* rich text in a qtableview with custom delegates reimplementing the paint method such as:

```
void CHtmlDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                          const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt(option);

    QLabel *label = new QLabel;
    label->setText(index.data().toString());
    label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
    label->setGeometry(option.rect);
    label->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : transparent; }");

    painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
    label->render(painter);
    painter->translate(-option.rect.topLeft());
}
```

However, it will not make hyperlinks clickable.

To do so, you can use the following hack. Reimplement the setModel method of your table/list view and use setIndexWidget.

```
void MyView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *m)
{
  if (!m)
    return;

  QTableView::setModel(m);

  const int rows = model()->rowCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
      QModelIndex idx = model()->index(i, 1);

      QLabel *label = new QLabel;
      label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
      label->setText(model()->data(idx, CTableModel::HtmlRole).toString());
      label->setOpenExternalLinks(true);

      setIndexWidget(idx, label);
    }
}
```

In the example above, I replace column 1 with qlabels. Note that you need to void the display role in the model to avoid overlapping data.

Anyway, I would be interested in a better solution based on delegates.

Comment: What is CTableModel :: HtmlRole?  'CTableModel' has not been declared

Comment: what about any memory leak on the `new QLabel` in the former approach?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, its not that easy to render a `QLabel` with `setOpenExternalLinks()` when using a `QTableView` (as opposed to using a `QTableWidget`). There are no magic two lines of code you can call and have the job done.

1. use a delegate
2. set the delegate to the column of your table
3. use `QTextDocument` combined with `setHTML()` to render a html link
4. this means your model needs to provide an HTML fragment containing `a href`
5. calculate the geometry of the link and provide event handlers for to intercept the mouse

   - change the cursor when it is over the link
   - execute the action when the link is clicked
6. what a mess :( i want `painter->setWidgetToCell()`

--

```
void LabelColumnItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    if( option.state & QStyle::State_Selected )
        painter->fillRect( option.rect, option.palette.highlight() );


    painter->save();

    QTextDocument document;                         // <---- RichText 
    document.setTextWidth(option.rect.width());

    QVariant value = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole);
    if (value.isValid() && !value.isNull())
    {
        document.setHtml(value.toString());        // <---- make sure model contains html

        painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
        document.drawContents(painter);        
    }

    painter->restore();
}
```